# How to share only audio from iPad to Mac?

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, audio, airplay

Currently on iPads 15.4 and MacBook, 12.3.1.

On MacBook, I have my Bluetooth earphone connected.

The only way to share audio and video from iPad to MacBook I can see is with AirPlay.

I see MacBook, under Speakers and TV, on the iPad airplay option.

When I select the MacBook on the iPad, then it starts to share the video and audio both.

And it takeovers the MacBook screen to show the video and nothing else you could do.

Is there any way to share only audio from Mac to iPad and keep the video on iPad, but listen to the audio on mac?

Answer (score 1):

Not with first party settings and apps. You would want to pair the headphones with the iPad if that’s how you wish to listen.

Most of the “mirroring” both first party and third party are video / audio in a mirroring situation - not a override the audio routing.

- https://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector

The [new shared keyboard feature on iOS and macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212757) would let you grab a video playing from the iPad and drag it to the Mac and play it there, but the only tool I think that might address your situation would be this from Rogue Amoeba:

- https://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/mac/
- https://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/satellite/

And you likely need their Satellite app on the iPad.

Comment: This type of stuff is why I sold my ipad. As a PC producer, I found the two things severely incompatible and analog headphones output always sounds like garbage on every interface I've used. The plan now is definitely go all apple in the future, because stuff like this sounds amazing. As far as using your phone as a midi controller, this is also pretty simple on Android/Windows, but I've never found a need for it.

Comment: When you’re ready to look again, hopefully Apple or Rogue Amoeba has what you need for your sound routing,  @adomanim